# Use array as sort order

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I want to use an array of strings as template how to order other arrays.

```
var sort = ["this","is","my","custom","order"];
```

and then i want to sort an array of objects depending on a key (content) by that order:

```
var myObjects = [
    {"id":1,"content":"is"},
    {"id":2,"content":"my"},
    {"id":3,"content":"this"},
    {"id":4,"content":"custom"},
    {"id":5,"content":"order"}
];
```

so that my result is:

```
sortedObject = [
    {"id":3,"content":"this"},        
    {"id":1,"content":"is"},
    {"id":2,"content":"my"},
    {"id":4,"content":"custom"},
    {"id":5,"content":"order"}    
];
```

how would i do that?

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this with help of **[`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)** and **[`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)**

```js
var sort = ["this", "is", "my", "custom", "order"];

var myObjects = [{
  "id": 1,
  "content": "is"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "content": "my"
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "content": "this"
}, {
  "id": 4,
  "content": "custom"
}, {
  "id": 5,
  "content": "order"
}];

var sortedObj = myObjects.sort(function(a, b) {
  return sort.indexOf(a.content) - sort.indexOf(b.content);
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(sortedObj, null, 3) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
var sort = ["this", "is", "my", "custom", "order"];
var myObjects = [{
   "id": 1,
   "content": "is"
}, {
   "id": 2,
   "content": "my"
}, {
   "id": 3,
   "content": "this"
}, {
   "id": 4,
   "content": "custom"
}, {
   "id": 5,
   "content": "order"
}];
var myObjectsSort = sort.map(function(e, i) {
   for (var i = 0; i < myObjects.length; ++i) {
      if (myObjects[i].content == e)
         return myObjects[i];
   }
});
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(myObjectsSort , null, 3) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

> Create a new array and place the every object from `myObjects` considering `index` of the `sort`

Try this:

```js
var sort = ["this", "is", "my", "custom", "order"];
var myObjects = [{
  "id": 1,
  "content": "is"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "content": "my"
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "content": "this"
}, {
  "id": 4,
  "content": "custom"
}, {
  "id": 5,
  "content": "order"
}];
var newArr = [];
myObjects.forEach(function(item) {
  var index = sort.indexOf(item.content);
  newArr[index] = item;
});
console.log(newArr);
```

```html
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use an object for the storing of the sort order.

```js
var sort = ["this", "is", "my", "custom", "order"],
    sortObj = {},
    myObjects = [{ "id": 1, "content": "is" }, { "id": 2, "content": "my" }, { "id": 3, "content": "this" }, { "id": 4, "content": "custom" }, { "id": 5, "content": "order" }];

sort.forEach(function (a, i) { sortObj[a] = i; });

myObjects.sort(function (a, b) {
    return sortObj[ a.content] - sortObj[ b.content];
});
 
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(myObjects, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```